# How to query Salesforce using multiple emails from a csv file?

Tags: soql, data-loader, developer-console

I'm trying to export data from Salesforce but only those that match the emails I have in a csv file. I'm thinking of using Dataloader but I don't know exactly how to do that.

I checked the Developer Console and try two emails but it didn't work. Here's what I did:

```
SELECT Id, LastName, FirstName, Email FROM Contact WHERE Email LIKE ('someone@company.com', 'sometwo@company.com')
```

I have over a thousand emails in my csv file and I wanted to use this as a reference to export the records from Salesforce.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use IN operator

SELECT Id, LastName, FirstName, Email FROM Contact WHERE Email IN ('someone@company.com', 'sometwo@company.com')

Comment: thank you! This worked on the developer console.  